# Razor Declarative Helper Conditional Attributes - class with space not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I'm facing a problem, I have a Razor Helper like this. I cant have multiple classes like this **class="test test2"** from a generated string by merging the attributes supplied and default attributes.

Here is the helper code.

```
@helper TextBox(string label
    , string inputId
    , [Optional]object divAttributes
    , [Optional]object labelAttributes
    , [Optional]object inputAttributes)
{
    <div @ControlsHelper.GenerateAttributes(new 
        { @class = @GetClass(ControlClasses.Field) }, divAttributes)>
        <label @ControlsHelper.GenerateAttributes(new 
            { @for = inputId }, divAttributes)>@label</label>
        <input type="text" @ControlsHelper.GenerateAttributes(new 
            { id = inputId }, divAttributes)>
    </div>
}
```

now the problem here is this.

```
@ControlsHelper.GenerateAttributes(new 
        { @class = @GetClass(ControlClasses.Field) }, divAttributes)
```

lets say the **divAttributes** contains the following attributes.

```
new
{
    @class = "SampleAdditionalClass",
    id = "myId"
}
```

Now the method produces this result (Type is `IHtmlString`)

```
{class=field ronald}
```

This is correct as it's supposed to merge the classes and add space between. But when it gets rendered in the UI, it produces this.

```
<div class="field" sampleadditionalclass="">
```

Any good reason why this happens?

For those who wants to know the code of GenerateAttributes, here

```
public static IHtmlString GenerateAttributes(object defaultAttributes
    , [Optional]object suppliedAttributes)
{
    var defaultValues = defaultAttributes.ToRouteDictionary() 
        ?? new RouteValueDictionary();
    var suppliedValues = suppliedAttributes.ToRouteDictionary() 
        ?? new RouteValueDictionary();
    if (defaultValues == null)
        return new HtmlString(string.Empty);

    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var suppliedAttrib in suppliedValues)
    {
        if (suppliedAttrib.Key.ToLower() == "class")
        {
            if (defaultValues.ContainsKey(suppliedAttrib.Key))
                defaultValues[suppliedAttrib.Key] 
                    += string.Format(" {0}", suppliedAttrib.Value);
            else
                defaultValues.Add(suppliedAttrib.Key, suppliedAttrib.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            if (defaultValues.ContainsKey(suppliedAttrib.Key))
                defaultValues.Remove(suppliedAttrib.Key);

            defaultValues.Add(suppliedAttrib.Key, suppliedAttrib.Value);
        }
    }
    builder.Append(string.Join(" ", defaultValues.Select(x => 
        $"{x.Key}={x.Value}")));
    return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What do the values in `defaultValues` for the class key look like in the `GenerateAttributes` method? Are they both the same, ie. no commas, apostrophes etc.

Comment: @Steve Yes, they're the same, no commas

Comment: Then I suspect Yura's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you just simply need to add quotes to your format string:

```
builder.Append(string.Join(" ", defaultValues.Select(x => 
    $"{x.Key}=\"{x.Value}\"")));
```

Without quotes browser will treat spase separated text as different attributes, and add `=""` to it automatically.

Comment: Thanks, seems i overlooked this, i tried this but there may have been a problem on my parameters, thankyou